# java- Pedir numero por teclado y construir array

Tags: java, array, scanner, java-util-scanner, integer

soy estudiante de programación y debo realizar un programa que introduciendo un numero cualquiera por scanner me cree un array de 10 elementos.Pero no logro pedir el numero y crear el array de 10 elementos.

Un ejemplo seria algo así:

```
Pido numero:
5
56789101112131415
menu:
//.....
Elige una opcion:
1
se modifica la posición numero 2 mediante numero introducido.
//etc.....
```

Edito: (adjunto mi codigo) - Este es mi codigo, pero no puedo continuar con mi menú ya que el paso de pedir un numero y convertirlo en array no se hacerlo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
    int num2 = lector.nextInt();

    int vector[]=new int [10];

    for (int i = vector[num2]; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(vector[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Menu, etc..");

    System.out.println("Elige una opción");
    int num =  lector.nextInt();

    menu(num,vector);

    lector.close();
}

public static void menu(int opcion, int [] vector) {

    do {
        switch (opcion){
        case 1:
            System.out.println(vector);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;  
        }
    }
    while(opcion!=7);
    System.out.println("Fin.");
}
}
```

resultado de este codigo:

```
Introduce un numero
5
0000000000
Menu Principal
==============
//menu
```

Comment: Buenas, la programación es resolver el problema en varios más pequeños, por lo tanto no vas a encontrar la solución, primero, busca como obtener un número por internet, después, busca como se construyen array y así... poco a poco, cuando tengas "código", vienes y planteas el problema u error.

Comment: Hola Edu, yo ya se crear un array y como pedir un numero a través del scanner, también tengo mi menú, ya que pedir el array es el primer paso del ejercicio que debo realizar, pero estoy atascada ya que no se como debo pedir un solo numero a través del scanner y que se convierta en array.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta, poniendo el código que llevas.

Comment: listo. Ya he modificado la pregunta con mi codigo

Comment: Creo que tomaste mal los apuntes, creo que el array lo tienes que crear con la longitud que te diga el usuario, línea 4 que creas el array de 10, sobra, y tendrás que crearlo con la longitud de línea 3 (num2) que para eso lo estás pidiendo. -----   int vector[]=new int [num2];

Comment: @azucarilla No entiendo bien. Lo que quieres es crear 10 elementos a partir de X número, por ejemplo, si ingreso el número 2500, debo generar números a partir de 2500 y llenarlo en el vector (obviamente en la primera posición del vector estará el 2500 como su valor inicial), es decir, en este caso mi arreglo tendrá valores de 2500 hasta 2509. ¿Eso es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: si exactamente eso, guardar el vector y a continuación usarlo en el menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm bueno después de leer los comentarios, al parecer lo que deberías hacer es cambiar tu "for" de la siguiente manera:

```
int vector[]=new int [10];

for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
    vector[i] = num2 + i; // Con esto asignas valores a cada posición de tu array
    System.out.print(vector[i]);
}
```

Una vez asignado un valor para cada posición de tu array ya puedes utilizarlo para los otros calculos de tu menú

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por intentar entender mi descripción, que se que a veces me cuesta explicarme claramente. Exactamente quería hacer eso!!

Answer (score 1):

Explicaré porque este bloque de código no funcionará:

```
System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
int num2 = lector.nextInt();

int vector[]=new int [10];

for (int i = vector[num2]; i < vector.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(vector[i]);
}
```

No funcionará porqué en ningún momento estamos asignando los elementos al vector a partir del número ingresado por el usuario.

Por ejemplo, si ingreso el número `3`, la variable `i` recibirá como valor un `0` porqué todos los elementos del vector fue inicializado a `0`, de forma predeterminada y es evidente, que en pantalla imprimirá puros `0`.

Pero esto se puede volver peligroso, ¿que pasaría si `num2` vale 5000? Habría un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), esto puede provocar sobreescritura de memoria (escribir en espacios de memoria que le pertenezcan al propio programa o incluso al sistema) o incluso el programa podría dejar de funcionar.

Con respecto a tu duda, para poder generar elementos en el vector a partir de un número ingresado por el usuario, debes usar el siguiente código:

```
//El primer elemento del vector, será el valor que tenga num2.
vector[0] = num2;
for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++) 
{
    vector[i] = num2 + i;
    System.out.print(vector[i]);
}
```

Ahora, si `num2` vale 5000, en pantalla debería dar:

```
5001
5002
5003
5004
5005
5006
5007
5008
5009
```

Comment: Hola!! tu explicación ha sido muy útil para mi! sin ella no hubiera entendido, lo que estaba haciendo! ademas me gustaria darte las gracias por tomarte un tiempo en leer mi pregunta y tratar de entenderla, ya que muchas veces no logro expresar con claridad lo que trato de decir. Estaba entre tu respuesta y la del chico de arriba porque ambas son muy buenas! pero al final he dado por valida la del chicode arriba, ya que justo era lo que estaba buscando. Igualmente sin tu ayuda no hubiera comprendido nada de esto, gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

> Lo que veo es un error de concepto, en tu codigo estas recorriendo el arreglo desde el numero que recolectas hasta el final del arreglo, y como nunca ingresaste un valor al arreglo te imprime 0, por ejemplo si engresas 5, te devuelve 00000. 
>   Recolectar el numero lo haces bien, guardas en num2 el entero que igresas por consola.
>   Despues definis e inicializas el vector.

```
int vector[]=new int [10];
//personalmente yo lo hago int[] vector= new int[10];  porque el arreglo es de 
//enteros pero si te funciona...
```

> cuando lo inicializas se reserva en memoria los 10 espacios con su respectivo incide en la memoria, Java por default si no le asignas valores como son enteros te inicializa en 0 todos los buckets (cuadraditos o cubos).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego para asignar un valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El número que esta entre corechetes[] se llama indice, en un arreglo (vector) de capacidad 10 vas a tener de 0 a 9 indices, para recorrer todo el arreglo se puede usar un bucle for.  Si lo quiero recorrer desde el principio hasta el final seria.

```
for(int i = 0; i<vector.length;i++){
   //sentencias
}
```

> La traduccion seria para i=0 (el primer indice del arreglo) hasta i

```
System.out.println(vector[0]);
//resultado en pantalla; 5;
System.out.println(vector[6]);
```

//resultado en pantalla 8.

> Ahora que te mostre como funciona, te puedo responder, si queres ingresar por consola un numero al arreglo, tenes que pedir la ubicación y el numero, o incremetar una variable que vaya cambiando el indice. el sig. ejemplo es con la segunda.

```
private static int[] vector;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
int num2 = lector.nextInt();
vector =new int [10];
//para insertar un entero nuevo
insertar(num2);

//para modificar necesitas pedir el indice (num) y el numero para modificar(num2)
modificar(num,num2);

//para mostrarlos todos:
mostrarTodo();
}
private static void insertar(int num){
   for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
     vector[i]=num+i;
   }


}
private static void editar(int indice, int num){
  if(indice>vector.length-1||inice<0)
    System.out.println("indice invalido");
  else
    vector[indice]=num;   
}
private static void mostrarTodo(){
  for(int i=0; i<vector.length;i++)
     System.out.println(vector[i]);
}
```

> Lo que te enseña este ejercicio, es programar de forma modular, recorrido exhaustivo y no exhaustivo y como usar un vector.
>   DATO DE COLOR. un recorrido no exhaustivo es el mismo for pero con una condicion de corte, por ejemplo.

```
boolean corte= false;
for(int i=0;i<vector.length&&!corte;i++){
  if(vector[i]==NUMERO_BUSCADO)
    corte=true;
}
```